# Execute some logic before every stateless bean method

Tags: java, events, ejb, stateless-session-bean

I need to execute a logic before every call in a stateless bean method.

Example:

```
class MyStatelessBean
{
   void myPreExecutionLogic()
   {
       System.out.println("pre method execution logic");
   }

   void method1()
   {
       System.out.println("method 1");
   }

   void method2()
   {
       System.out.println("method 2");
   }
}
```

There is a way of doing this using EJB? Registering some kind of listener or annotating the myPreExecutionLogic like @PreConstruct?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using EJB3, you can use [Interceptors](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/meeraj/archive/2006/01/interceptors_wi.html) and `@AroundInvoke`

Set up an interceptor class with the @AroundInvoke annotation

```
public class MyInterceptor {

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object doSomethingBefore(InvocationContext inv) {
         // Do your stuff here.
         return inv.proceed();
    }
}
```

Then annotate your ejb methods with the class name

```
public class MyStatelessBean {

       @Interceptors ( {MyInterceptor.class} )
       public void myMethod1() {
```

Comment: hum, ok. I read the [article](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/meeraj/archive/2006/01/interceptors_wi.html) that you mentioned and conclude that the example below will solve part of my problem.
'class MyStatelessBean
{
   @AroundInvoke
   void myPreExecutionLogic(InvocationContext invocationContext)<br/>
   {
       System.out.println("pre method execution logic");<br/>
   }
   void method1()
   {
       System.out.println("method 1");
   }
}'
There is a way of doing this in a abstract super class?
I need that all the subclasses methods to be intercepted.

Comment: @Wagner -- Yes. You can define your interceptor on the super class itself. Then all the subclass methods will be intercepted.

Answer (score 1):

A little variation of Kal's answer, I managed to make the method in the same class as the example declared (reminds me of junits @Before).

Also don't forget the "throws Exception" of the method signature for exceptions thrown from the actual method call inside `ctx.proceed()`

```
class MyStatelessBean
{

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object myPreExecutionLogic(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("pre method execution logic");

        return ctx.proceed();
    }

   void method1()
   {
       System.out.println("method 1");
   }

   void method2()
   {
       System.out.println("method 2");
   }
}
```